# Duplicating rows in a mysql table without enumerating fields

Tags: mysql, auto-increment, temp-tables

This mysql table has an autoincrement field. I want to duplicate some rows. I thought I will use a temporary table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmptab SELECT * FROM mytab WHERE somecondition = 1;
```

Before copying the data back to mytab I can now do some updates in tmptab.

```
UPDATE tmptab ... /* some updates */;
```

Because mytab has an autoincrement field I cannot simply copy the contents of tmptab to mytab. One solution would be to enumarate fields (and omit the autoincrement field).

I am looking for a solution without enumerating fields. This has advantages, for instance when fields will be added later.

I thougth I could erase the autoincrement field in tmptab (removing the autoincrement column) and then use a query similar to this one:

```
INSERT INTO mytab SELECT *  FROM tmptab;
```

Would this work? The autoincrement field in mytab should be set correctly. Or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thougth I could erase the autoindex field in tmptab (removing the autoindex column) and then use a query similar to this one

You need to use a command like this:

```
UPDATE tmptab SET key_column=NULL
```

When you insert NULLs back into the original table, it will generate new auto_increment ids.

You might need to add a command to drop the primary key index on the temp table for this to work.